# How to change color each time mousewheel is activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I'm trying to change the color of the text when the mouse wheel scrolls up. I want to change it once to red on the first scroll, then change it to blue on the second scroll. What I have is not working but hopefully you can see my logic.

```
   $('#content').bind('mousewheel',function(event) {
        var scroll_up   = event.originalEvent.deltaY > 120;
        var red         = $('#content').css('color', 'red');
        var blue        = $('#content').css('color', 'blue');

        if(scroll_up) {
            console.log('you scrolled up!');
            //change color to red
            red;
        }
        if(red && scroll_up){
            console.log('you scrolled up again!');
            //change color to blue
            blue;
        }
    });
```

Comment: ` var red         = $('#content').css('color', 'red');
        var blue        = $('#content').css('color', 'blue');` you already assigned the color to #content, when you check the scroll condition you are not changing the property in #content

Comment: Use [the `scroll` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this:

```
$('#content').bind('mousewheel',function(event) {
        var scroll_up   = event.originalEvent.deltaY > 120;


        if(scroll_up) {
            console.log('you scrolled up!');
            //change color to red

            changeColor(red);
        }
        if(red && scroll_up){
            console.log('you scrolled up again!');
            //change color to blue
            changeColor(blue);
        }
    });

function changeColor(color){

    $('#content').css('color', color);
}
```

*i haven't  tested the code, but it should work as intended.

Your code doesn't work because you already assigned the color before the condition was meet, so the last color was the only one you are seing.

Comment: recommend using the [Wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event rather than MouseWheel. MouseWheel is not a standards-track event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content').bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    var content = $('#content');
    var scrollUp = (event.originalEvent.deltaY / 120 > 0);
    if (scrollUp) {
        var isRed = (content.css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');

        console.log('you scrolled up!');

        if (isRed) {
            content.css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)');
        } else {
            content.css('color', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');
        }
    }
});
```